# Sample_NIUserTracker in openni_kinect?

Tags: openni, openi-tracker, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

where can i find the Sample-NiUserTracker Viewer in the new kinect stack?
The openni_tracker works fine and i can see the skeleton tranformations in rviz, 
but I miss the GUI Viewer for easier people tracking.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9395/sample_niusertracker-in-openni_kinect?/) by [Dark-Valentine](https://answers.ros.org/users/282/dark-valentine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The new stack doesn't have a standalone program for tracking users. Maybe because it's not a part of ROS i.e. a standalone. You might have to use the old binary in the "ni" stack.

`roscd ni`
`cd openni/bin/`
`./Sample-NiUserTracker`

---

Originally posted by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) with karma: 284 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-25**:
thats great, cause I've been switching between ni stack and openni_kinect sometimes

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-24**:
It's not there because it adds noteable dependencies etc.  I've opened a ticket to add a deb of the example applications https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/10